# I cannot get the javaScript to do the function i am requesting it to do, in my case multiply two values by a hidden and then add a final value

Tags: javascript

I am so lost as to why this is not working properly, as it is on similar previous code.  This is for field personnel, a cheat Sheet to simply enter values and get a fast answer (calculation).  They enter the value of Num5/6/7 code multiplies 3 values one hidden then adds the last value together and upon click button the result is shown.

Here is my code (taken from copy/paste of a working conversion).

```
        <div class="containerHydro">
            <p>
            <label >Fluid Column Length</label>
            <input type="number" id="num5">
            <label >Fluid Weight</label>
            <input type="number" id="num6">
            <label >Well Head Pressure</label>
            <input type="number" id="num7">
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="calculate()"/>
            </p>
            <p id="total1"></p>
       </div>
```

The Function also copy/paste of multiply two int then divide by hidden (which works BTW)

```
  function calculate() {
    var numFive = document.getElementById('num5').value;
    var numSix = document.getElementById('num6').value;
    var numSvn = document.getElementById('num7').value;
    var total1 = parseInt(numFive) * parseInt(numSix) * 0.052 + parseInt('numSvn');
    var p =document.getElementById('total1');
    p.innerHTML += total1;
  }
```

Here is the same idea which works fine- 
Code-

```
       <div class="container7">
            <p>
            <label id="H2S Percent">H2S Percentage</label> 
            <input id="num3" type="number" name="num3" placeholder="H2S Percent">
            <label id="H2S Percent">WHP</label> 
            <input id="num4" type="number" name="num4"placeholder="Well Head Pressure" > <br>
            </p>     
            <input type="button" value="H2S Partial Pressure"  onclick="math()"/>            
            <p id="result"></p>
       </div>
```

Function

```
function math() {
   var numThree = document.getElementById('num3').value;
   var numFour = document.getElementById('num4').value;
   var result = parseInt(numThree) * parseInt(numFour) / 1000000;
   var p = document.getElementById('result');
   p.innerHTML += result;
 }
```

Comment: Your calculate() function doesn't work as intended, because you are adding the text value 'numSvn' parsed to integer and not the variable numSvn.

Comment: The issue is ur `parseInt('numSvn');` Remove the quotes to `parseInt(numSvn);`

Comment: Can you kindly show me the correct function as you described- apologies i am very new, while i understand you i do not see it in code.. yet anyway lol hopefully.

Comment: @SkidFx In the function calculate(), this line `var total1 = parseInt(numFive) * parseInt(numSix) * 0.052 + parseInt('numSvn');`

Comment: Hi Dark- I removed quotes and the sum still does not show up upon clicking button. Any other advise?

Comment: Function is now - ```  function calculate() {
    var numFive = document.getElementById('num5').value;
    var numSix = document.getElementById('num6').value;
    var numSvn = document.getElementById('num7').value;
    var total1 = parseInt(numFive) * parseInt(numSix) * 0.052 + parseInt(numSvn);
    var p =document.getElementById('total1');
    p.innerHTML += total1;
  }```

Comment: I posted an answer with is working. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Dark/Ali - The laughs definitely on me today guys- - i did not link my javascript to the html page i made. Thanks Team!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
  var numFive = document.getElementById('num5').value;
  var numSix = document.getElementById('num6').value;
  var numSvn = document.getElementById('num7').value;
  var total1 = parseInt(numFive) * parseInt(numSix) * 0.052 + parseInt(numSvn);
  var p = document.getElementById('total1');
  p.innerHTML += total1;
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerHydro">
  <p>
    <label>Fluid Column Length</label>
    <input type="number" id="num5">
    <label>Fluid Weight</label>
    <input type="number" id="num6">
    <label>Well Head Pressure</label>
    <input type="number" id="num7">
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="calculate()" />
    </p>
    <p id="total1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dark - I forgot to link the script to the HTML. And removed the Quotes! Working great.